# Is there a way to include a separate attachment control to a Work Item Type in TFS

Tags: tfs, customization, tfs-workitem, tfs-process-template

I'm customizing work item types in TFS (Team Foundation Server - 2013), and I'd like to know if it is possible to add more than one AttachmentControl to a WorkItemType.

I've tried adding another control of type `AttachmentsControl` but to no avail, because if I add an attachment inside one control, it appears on the other as well.

[image]

To make myself clear, I have a work item type called `Change`, which in turn has two different tabs, one to store the communication plan, and the other to store the backup plan. These tabs would have just one `AttachmentsControl` which would hold the respective plans. The plans are simple excel (XLSX) files.

Here's what happens when I add an attachment (print from web, but on visual studio the same thing happens):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one attachment store per work item. Any attachments that you add will always appear in all controls.

Comment: Well this is unsettlingly unthought of, since the editor allows you to add more than one `AttachmentsControl` :(. Thanks for the confirmation, I'll accept as answer after a couple days if no one comes up with a work around.